# Architecture governance activities

Tags: architecture

I'm beginner as an architect, just wondering what kind of activities should be considered during architecture governance process? I have seen couple of different answers and little bit confused on it, appreciate any recommendations. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like there are many methodologies for implementing software (e.g. Agile, Waterfall, etc) there are many methodologies and frameworks for architecture governance.

One example of an architecture framework is TOGAF. It includes principles and methodology for architecture governance in an enterprise. You may want to have a look at chapter 44, for reference: https://pubs.opengroup.org/architecture/togaf9-doc/arch/chap44.html

Generally speaking, architecture governance may range from a conscious decision to let solutions grow organically (i.e. essentially no governance) to complete frameworks like TOGAF, which suggest a central body that govern architecture in an enterprise by reviewing architecture in an architecture board, establishing architecture principles for the organization to follow, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the response Lennart.  I agree architecture review is surely part of the governance process, but the puzzle is about when to perform the review. In spirit of Agile I don't want architecture review is a hard stop or must before delivery squad starts solution implementation, but concerned the negative impact when gaps are found during the architecture review if the review is after implementation done, how to tradeoff this?

Comment: As you've already mention Owen, it's a trade-off between agility and governance. One way to pre-empt a situation where development has already made significant progress in the wrong direction before uncovered in a review, is to have clear architecture principles that ensure that the delivery squads are aligned with 'the big picture'.

Another approach I have seen is to have two or three reviews, e.g. 20%, 60% and 80% throughout the project. By having early and continuous alignment between architecture and delivery, the reviews becomes smaller and is less likely to deviate significantly.

Comment: Thank you very much Lennart, this makes perfect sense!